# Programmatically turning on <strong></strong> for editable section in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an HTML5/javascript/php project where I have a  which is set to be editable.

I know the user can be press `ctrl + b` to make the text bold, but I also want to allow the user to be able to click on the appropriate button on the web page to perform the same action.

I.e. when the user types it will be in normal text, they click on the bold button on the web page and it appends `<strong>` to the html of the section, and whatever they type now will be hold until they press the button again and it then appends `</strong>`.

However, at the moment when I append `<strong>` it seems to automatically add `</strong>` and I want to stop that from happening. Am I going about this the right way or is there a better way that this can be achieved.

Below is the javascript that I am trying to use

```
function enableDisableBold(section)
{
    var boldEnabled = $("#boldEnabled").val();
    var content = $("#" + section).html();
    var newContent;
    if (boldEnabled == "true")
    {
        $("#btnBold").removeClass("formatButtonsActivated");
        $("#boldEnabled").val("false");
        //newContent = content + "</strong>";
        //$("#" + section).html(newContent);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#btnBold").addClass("formatButtonsActivated");
        $("#boldEnabled").val("true");
        newContent = content + "<strong>";
        $("#" + section).html(newContent.replace("</strong>", ""));
    }

    alert($("#" + section).html());
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
I've just come across another solution which does what I want to achieve, but there is a slight issue. At the end of the function call, I perform the following bit of code.

var article = document.getElementById(section);
article.focus();
document.execCommand("Bold", false, null);

The problem is this is working fine in Internet Explorer, but in Chrome is where I am having the problem. When I set the focus back to the `<section>` tag, it puts the cursor back to the beginning of the text. I read somewhere that putting `onfocus="this.value = this.value;"` on the control but this doesn't help.

I was trying to find a way of putting the cursor back to the end of the character, but I would actually need to put the cursor back to where it originally was. Is this something that can be done.

Comment: If you wait to add the closing tag, wouldn't that make the text not look bold in the meantime? I think you need to append the characters to the end of the content of the <strong> tag. And I'd rename your function `toggleBold(section)`, and then make two new methods enable and disable to keep functions small

Answer (score 0):

create a strong element and append your content to it

```
$('<strong />').append(content);
```